# Change back button image conditionally, iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, back, navigationbar

Consider the following scenario:

- When entering view, back-button is normal, (left-arrow).
- Once user has started adding stuff to a list, the button becomes a trashcan in order to tell the user that progress is lost if back-button is pressed.

Is it possible to make the back-button listen to a list and change once it has one or more elements?

I have tried

```
[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage;
```

But that changes the back-button in the whole application… and I only want it changed in the current view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[UIBarButtonItem appearance]` is a proxy used to globally set appearance settings

You should use `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` to set the image for a given view controller

Comment: I succeeded to change to the trashcan-button, but I fail when I try to change back into the back-button.. self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash
                                                                                              target:self
                                                                                              action:@selector(back)];

Comment: you should just not change the default back button

Comment: what do you mean? The whole point was to change the back button when items > 0, and have default button when items = 0.

Comment: ah i was thinking it was different pushes. try setting left bar button item to nil?